# Odometer.js Keeps Updating From 0

Tags: javascript, odometer

I'm working on a counter that shows the total amount of trees from TeamTrees.org (I'm new to JavaScript) Which I wanted to make it real-time. So, I use Odometer.js and it keeps updating from 0.

Here's the video to describe my problem.
*removed*

I've tried searching on this site, and other Sites. But, it still didn't work.

Here's the code:

index.html

```
</div>
    <script src="trees.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/odometer.js/0.4.8/odometer.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    init();

     var TreeCount = new Odometer({ 
        el: document.querySelector('#cash'),
        auto: 'true', 
        format: ',ddd', 
        theme: 'default'
         }) 
    </script>
    </center>
</body>
```

Trees.js

```
function init() { 
fetchTrees() 
setInterval(fetchTrees, 3000);
   } 
  function formatNumber(x) {
return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    }
 function fetchTrees() { 
   $.ajax({
    url: "-",
    method: "POST",
  data: {
   "wrapAPIKey": "-"
 }
  }).done(function(data) {
    numTrees = data["data"]["#totalTrees"]; 

  $("#cash").text("$"+formatNumber(numTrees))
  TreeCount.update(numTrees); 
   });
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you need to add the last retrieved value to the new value like so :

```
function init() { 
fetchTrees() 
setInterval(fetchTrees, 3000);
   } 
  function formatNumber(x) {
return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    }
 function fetchTrees() { 
   $.ajax({
    url: "-",
    method: "POST",
  data: {
   "wrapAPIKey": "-"
 }
  }).done(function(data) {
    numTrees += parseInt(data["data"]["#totalTrees"]); 

  $("#cash").text("$"+formatNumber(numTrees))
  TreeCount.update(numTrees); 
   });
 }
```

Comment: it says that numTrees is not defined.  It says                                                     Uncaught ReferenceError: numTrees is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (trees.js:16)
    at i (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2)
    at A (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4)

Comment: if you define numTrees right before onInit(), as follows : 
    var numTrees=0;

Comment: It's still the same. The Odometer.js still updating from 0

Comment: Here's the code: `function init() { 
  fetchTrees() 
  setInterval(fetchTrees, 10000);
     } 
    function formatNumber(x) {
  return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
      }
   function fetchTrees() { 
     $.ajax({
      url: "-",
      method: "POST",
    data: {
     "wrapAPIKey": "-"
   }
    }).done(function(data) { 
      
      var numTrees = 0;
      numTrees += parseInt(data["data"]["#totalTrees"]); 
  
    $("#cash").text("$"+formatNumber(numTrees))
    TreeCount.update(numTrees); 
     });
   } `

Comment: I just saw try a new method and it works now. Thanks for your advice too!